# react-native scroll to index causing crash as the 'ref' of flatlist is undefined

Tags: react-native, scroll, react-native-flatlist

this is how i am trying to scroll

```
`if(this.refs && this.refs.flatList) {
      this.refs.flatList.scrollToIndex({index: selectedIndex, animated: true})
    }`
```

The problem is 'this.refs.flatlist' surprisingly is undefined sometimes and if i put a check that scroll only when the ref is defined then it never scrolls

Comment: How do you assign ref prop in your FlatList?

Comment: I don't know if this is too obvious, but you're referencing `this.ref.flatList` in the if clause, and `this.refs.array` inside it.

Comment: <FlatList ref='flatList'

Comment: @jevakallio yes thats the patch i have kept because my app was crashing sometime when 'this.refs.flatList' was undefined